# How to force uninstall a software that is installed by MSI package?

Tags: windows-installer, silverlight

Now my computer's Silverlight 5.1.10411.0 (x64) cannot be uninstalled because the MSI package is missing, how can I force it to uninstall? The reason that I want to do this is that I cannot redownload the installed of Silverlight 5.1.10411.0 (x64), there is a x86 one, but not x64 one - shame on you, Microsoft, or me for that I cannot find it using Google. Or if someone can point me to the right download package is also acceptable.

Comment: Download [Silverlight 64.exe](http://www.technize.net/?dl_id=31), hope it will help you.

Comment: Yes, thx, I downloaded it. Will try it out.

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: Gather your rage! Revo uninstall it!
http://superuser.com/questions/957981/force-msi-to-uninstall

Answer (score 20):

It is 2017 now, I found a better way of force uninstall an application without msi.

Download the [Program Install and Uninstall Troubleshooter](https://web.archive.org/web/20181122104102/http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/E/9/7E9188C0-2511-4B01-8B4E-0A641EC2F600/MicrosoftProgram_Install_and_Uninstall.meta.diagcab) ([alternate link](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/86975-program-install-uninstall-troubleshooter-windows.html)).

Run it => Uninstall => Select the program => Done

With this there is no need to touch registry and no need to download third party tools that may contains Malwares.

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work for me. What finally worked was an older tool called "Windows Installer Cleanup" which is available as a legacy download from external websites. This worked perfectly:http://www.softpedia.com/get/Security/Secure-cleaning/Windows-Installer-CleanUp-Utility.shtml

Comment: Worked for me to uninstall VirtualBox that was encountering some sorts of COM issue. Thanks!

Comment: This worked for me trying to uninstall OpenSSL from a MSI binary which I accidentally installed over the previous version. I'd installed the new version, then removed the old, but that broke the new version which I could neither uninstall, nor reinstall. After using this tool, I could install the new version again.

Comment: This worked for me! Thank you very much! I was having a hard time trying to uninstall Ablebits Ultimate (an add-in for Excel) where the error would be "could not find the MSI Installer".

Comment: This worked! I was able to uninstall KMS_VL_ALL_AIO without using any third party applications.

Answer (score 14):

Here is a little article I have been working on, and although it does not address your question directly, it might be useful. Just pay attention to the registry keys I mention and you can generally delete them, as well as the `C:\Program Files\Application` folder to trick the installers into think

#### Everything You Wanted to Know about Add / Remove Programs in Windows

Have you ever wondered how Windows presents and uses the Add/Remove programs? Or perhaps you have the need to enumerate these values yourself? Here is some useful information on how it works, how to use it and some neat tricks you might enjoy.

[image]
Everything you see in add and remove programs (XP, Vista, 7 confirmed) is written to the registry at **HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\** as a subkey.
[image]

For example, I have the subkey CutePDF Writer Installation with the keys and values:

Now, of interest here is the UninstallString value. When you click “uninstall” in Add/Remove programs, what it does is call this value and run it. You can do the same manually, for example with CutePDF if you run **`C:\Program Files (x86)\Acro Software\CutePDF Writer\Setup64.exe /uninstall`** from either the Run line or the command prompt, you will get the uninstaller. You could also find additional uninstall options by running the command with the `/?` switch, or run the following from the cmd prompt:

```
Cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Acro Software\CutePDF Writer
Setup64.exe /?
```

Note, this is a bad example as the switch does not return anything! But generally this will work, or you can just call the uninstaller manually this way.
Now, let’s look at a possible problem with the Uninstall list, you will see some files that names in this format: **{AFF7153F-C4AA-4C48-AEE9-8611D276CE86}**

This is how a MSI installer writes its name to the Registry, instead of writing the friendly name an EXE installer writes, it writes its GUID.

This is not really a problem, as much as a difficulty in reading the keys. There are couple ways to read through these. One, there is a Value Name DisplayName that will have the more friendly value of (in this example) Quest ActiveRoles Management Shell for Active Directory (x64).

Another approach, is Windows writes a “compressed and hashed” version of the GUID to another part of the Registry.

To Hash the value, take the GUID {AFF7153F-C4AA-4C48-AEE9-8611D276CE86} and reverse each set of hex digits.
AFF7153F becomes F3517FFA, C4AA becomes AA4C and on down the GUID until you have the following:
**{F3517FFA-AA4C-84C4-9EEA-68EC672D1168}**

Now, drop the {, -, and } to get **F3517FFAAA4C84C49EEA68EC672D1168**.
You now have the compressed and hashed GUID that you can compare to another key.

You should now be able to find this new GUID at the following location in the Registry:
**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Products**

And sure enough, there she is:  [image: The Key hashed]

With the following keys:
 [image]

Again, you can then look in ProductName for the name of the application.

Bonus tip: You can launch the Add/remove programs by typing `appwiz.cpl` into the start search, run line or a command prompt.

Comment: It's a lot of information to grok, but after reading it, I think it's quite good. I'll try to find the uninstall information of Silverlight 5.1 and see what tricks I can apply

Comment: Looks like the hashed key you calculated `F3517FFAAA4C84C49EEA68EC672D1168` is not same as shown in the screenshot. I am also facing same when I follow your method. The last two sets are not reversed as a whole set but as a set of 2 hex numbers.

Comment: I have create a small python script to ease out manual operation and correcting above mentioned error. https://gist.github.com/joshiji/16a85e84d18cc12e9e606a987e23de6f

Comment: @skjoshi you're right on the screenshot! No clue why I did that nearly 4 years ago! Also, ewwwww Python...

Comment: "compressed and hashed"? What a dumb way to store GUID tables in the registry by Microsoft! Exactly what is gained by **reversing** the string? What were they thinking?!

Comment: @DRSDavidSoft it was developed in the mid / late 90's. It was if I had to assume meant to be a low level security measure for obfuscating how the MSI Installer worked...