# Force MSI To Uninstall

Tags: windows-10, uninstall, external-display, windows-installer

How can I force this to uninstall without the MSI?
The MSI is not on the website and [I tried extracting the MSI](https://superuser.com/q/957981/245425)... even installing with the EXE gives the exact same error below:

[image]

Comment: There is another answer on Stackoverflow that might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547809/extract-msi-from-exe

Comment: @mark I tried, I was getting some source files, not any MSI.

Comment: Can you install the driver again, then uninstall?

Comment: @moab I tried that using the EXE and it asks for the MSI

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Error shows that uninstaller was unable to find **FLUSBVGAx64.msi** in the computer & you could not find the **.msi** in website.

If you cannot find **FLUSBVGAx64.msi** in computer then you must look for other ways to uninstall the software.

**You cannot force a non existent .msi to uninstall a software**

Try one of these :

1. [Microsoft Install/Uninstall Fixit](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/mats/program_install_and_uninstall)
2. [Revo Uninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html)

*Note : I am not affiliated with any of these tools & recommending purely based on personal experience*

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention i am on windows 10. Isnt there a way to clean up registry And driver? Maybe revo?

Comment: If I am not using Microsoft fixit for some reason i do the manual job of removing the entries from Windows installer, then remove file associations if any, remove registry entries and then files from disk. if that sounds a lot to you, check if Revo uninstaller or iObit uninstaller works with Windows 10

Comment: Revo works. So remove all the registry entries via Revo uninstaller? And then try to install?

Comment: **Yes**. But revo also tries to call the built in uninstaller first and then you may get the sam error. you can ignore it and proceed with the removal of registry entries and then files from computer. Re-install after this should work fine.

Comment: Ah geez, I had done the Basic Revo uninstall instead of the Advanced... anyway, I gathered the rage to do the Advanced uninstall and install and external display works now! Thank you for your guidance.

Comment: A forced uninstall via Revo and then a registry clean via CCleaner for good lucked worked for me.